# HTML5 video positioning to the top

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

Does anyone know how to position the video content to the top, like "position: top" with background images?
I have a video that is 1920x1080px, but the div is currently using 1920x550px. I have tried to search the World Wide Web without any luck.

```
      <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
          <source src="vid/vid_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

Kindly,

Louis

Comment: did u tried **position:fixed; top:0;** ?

Comment: Thanks for adding a testable example. What is your expected result though? You want to **move** the video position itself **or** you want to **stretch** the viewing size upwards to 1080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it didn't work, but I've managed to fix it by setting the height:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop style="height: 1080px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

My example moves the video picture position to the top of page.

It won't be obvious that the video picture is at top since the navbar will block the view of it. So in **navbar** (is `<nav id="navbar" ... >` setup code), to move it down for testing, add this to the tag setup:

```
style="top:40px"
```

example setup:

```
<nav id="navbar" 
class="navbar navbar-expand-lg top-navbar sticky is-sticky" 
data-toggle="sticky-onscroll" 
style="top:40px">
```

Then find the div with `class="col-12 video-wrapper"` and add to its `"style"` ...

```
top: -60px
```

try a setup like this:

```
<div class="col-12 video-wrapper" 
style="background-image:url('vid/still_vid_3.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
min-height: 550px;
opacity: 0.4; 
top:-60px">

<video playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" controls="">
<source src="vid/vid_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and found that setting the video CSS height to "auto" worked for me.

Here is an example of editing the first line of your HTML code to include inline CSS:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop style="height: auto;">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).